# Custom Validation with Phalcon Model

Tags: php, validation, phalcon

I am trying to implement custom validation for my models. I am currently using successfully the included validators from Phalcon library, but when I try to implement mine, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
    <?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ValidatorInterface;
use Phalcon\Mvc\EntityInterface;

class MaxMinValidator extends Validator implements ValidatorInterface
{

    public function validate(EntityInterface $model)
    {
        $field  = $this->getOption('field');

        $min    = $this->getOption('min');
        $max    = $this->getOption('max');

        $value  = $model->$field;

        if ($min <= $value && $value <= $max) {
            $this->appendMessage(
                "The field doesn't have the right range of values",
                $field,
                "MaxMinValidator"
            );
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use it in my model like this:

```
public function validation()
{
        $this->validate(new MaxMinValidator(
            array(
                "field" => "Email",
                "min"   => 10,
                "max"   => 100
            )
        ));
 }
```

The class is correctly loaded, but doesn't execute the validation function and my code stops being executed after trying to validate. 
Note: This is the exact same code as found [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#implementing-a-business-rule).

Comment: Where did you create your class?
did u register the dir or namespace?

Comment: I created the class under a validator directory which I have registered in the bootstrap file.

Comment: What is the version of your phalcon? (check it from phpinfo())

Answer (score 2):

1.Check that your validator class is loaded properly. (create a function and write die("sth");) if calling that function causes your app to die you loaded the class properly.

2.Check your phalcon version if it under 2.0.5 you should modify your validator code to:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ValidatorInterface;
use Phalcon\Mvc\EntityInterface;

class MaxMinValidator extends Validator implements ValidatorInterface
{
    public function validate(\Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface $model)
    {
         $field  = $this->getOption('field');
         $min    = $this->getOption('min');
         $max    = $this->getOption('max');

         $value  = $model->$field;

         if ($min <= $value && $value <= $max) {
             $this->appendMessage(
             "The field doesn't have the right range of values",
             $field,
             "MaxMinValidator"
             );
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and if your phalcon version is 2.0.5 and your class is loaded but u can't see the validation error message add this method to your model class:

```
public function getMessages() {
    $messages = array();
    foreach (parent::getMessages() as $message) {
        switch ($message->getType()) {
            case 'InvalidCreateAttempt':
                $messages[] = 'The record cannot be created because it already exists';
                break;
            case 'InvalidUpdateAttempt':
                $messages[] = 'The record cannot be updated because it already exists';
                break;
            case 'PresenceOf':
                $messages[] = 'The field ' . $message->getField() . ' is mandatory';
                break;
            case 'MaxMinValidator':
                $messages[] = 'The field ' . $message->getField() . ' is not in range';
                break;
        }
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you check the whole function?

```
public function validation()
{
        $this->validate(new MaxMinValidator(
            array(
                "field" => "Email",
                "min"   => 10,
                "max"   => 100
            )
        ));

        // This line:
        return $this->validationHasFailed() != true;
 }
```

I think that you missed running `validationHasFailed` method.

Comment: I have this line: if ($this->validationHasFailed() == true)
  {
   return false;
  }        Although it doesn't even has the chance to get that line.

Comment: Hmm, then it something different. I'll try to look into it more - I'm curious myself of this.

Comment: Might be a bug in version 2.0, if the same thing does happen to you, I'll try to updated to 2.0.5 and if still happens I will open an issue on github.